# Please help me simplify this simple Ruby on Rails function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Could someone tell me how to simplify the following function in my `Invoice` model? It should return all `Invoices` related to a particular `Client` (both connected via a `Projects` table).

```
def self.search_by_client_id(client_id)
  if client_id
    projects = Project.where(:client_id => client_id)
    Invoice.where(:project_id => projects)
  else
    scoped
  end
end
```

I really can't get my head around this. Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like the perfect opportunity for a scope!

```
scope :client, lambda{|id| includes(:projects).where('projects.client_id = ?', id)}

Invoice.client(4).all # returns all invoices for the client with the specified ID.
```

Comment: The only problem is that I need to concatenate a number of search functions in my controller, like so: `@invoices = current_user.invoices.includes(:project).search_by_number(params[:query]).search_by_project_id(params[:project_id]).search_by_client_id(params[:client_id])`. And these searches should be connected in the SQL via *OR*, not *AND*. So I guess I can't use scopes here?

Comment: This is one way to tackle the problem, however it seems to duplicate built in ActiveRecord functionality via its associations. Simon Bagreev shows how to associate invoices to a client through projects in his answer. This allows to scope invoices through a client via "client.invoices" without the need to create a scope to explicitly do this.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you should be able to do it using ActiveRecord associations:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects
  has_many :invoices, :through => :project
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :invoices
  belongs_to :client
end

class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  has_one :client, :through => :project
end
```

Then, all `Invoices` related to a particular `Client`:

```
@client.invoices
```

To get a `Client`, associated to a particular invoice:

```
@invoice.client
```

Comment: Thanks! But I can't get your last two lines to work in my model for some reason.

Comment: I think Simon is missing an association in the Project class. It should include "belongs_to :client". This would allow the invoice to access the client via the project.

Comment: Yes, agreed. But what if I want to use different searches in my controller, e.g. `@invoices = current_user.invoices.includes(:project).search_by_number(params[:query]).search_‌​by_project_id(params[:project_id]).search_by_client_id(params[:client_id])` Isn't this a bit messy? Would be nice to solve this in the model somehow...